# Docker post build installations inside container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

Is there a convenient way to find out all installations and changes made inside a docker container after the container was built? Because its not recommended to commit the changes to a new image, how could I easily find out all changes so that I can put them in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker container diff` is what you need: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_diff/

Comment: Thank you thats very helpful, lets wait for more tips until I mark as solved

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to get helpful information.

To get logs of a container, use docker logs command, the syntax is:

```
# docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
```

For a full list of available options, run:

```
# docker logs --help
```

You can also pipe the output of the command to tools like `grep` to filter output. See example below.

```
# docker run  -it --rm --name test ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
root@fde8369a7439:/# apt-get update
root@fde8369a7439:/# apt-get install nginx
root@fde8369a7439:/# apt-get install vim
```

Now check the logs, grep for `apt-get`.

```
# docker logs test | grep apt-get
```

If you want to save the logs to a file on docker host machine, use:

```
# docker logs test > test_logs
```

You can also utilize bash history of a container to pull some info on what you did:

```
# docker exec container cat /root/.bash_history
```

The `docker diff` command is often used to inspect changes to files or directories on a container's filesystem. It doesn’t give you exact commands you execute but modified files.